# Brightness Problem

Tags: 14.04, brightness, lenovo

I have a lenovo z570 laptop. I have currently switched to Ubuntu 14.04. I am unable to control the brightness and it is always set to high. Please help. I have searched for the problem but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the screen brightness to your preferred level.

1.Open Terminal and enter

```
   cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
```

and note down the value.

2.Enter

```
  cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness
```

and note down the value.

3.Enter

```
    sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add these before the last line exit 0 in gedit:

```
   echo ValueFromStep1 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
   echo ValueFromStep2 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Change the values form step 1 and 2 accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple fix, you can download this Brightness Controller app:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/brightness-controller/

Hopefully it works for you. Did for me!