# screen brightness keys stopped working -- ubuntu 14.04 LTS -- HP notebook

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, brightness

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS last week on my HP Pavillion DV6700 notebook.
It was working perfectly until last night when I turned on the notebook and noticed the screen brightness was set to the minimun and two warnings of "application error" appeared on the screen.
My fn+f7 and fn+f8 shortcuts to raise or lower the screen brightness are not working anymore.

Input:

```
    ls /sys/class/backlight
```

Output

```
    acpi_video0
```

I also ran the acpi_listen command and then pressed my key shortcuts to raise or lower the screen brightness but no output was printed.

When I looked with nano at the grub file at

```
    /etc/default/
```

It showed:

```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

I already tried modifying it to "quiet splash video.use_native_backlight=1" but it does not work.
I also tried changing it to "quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor" and it still does not work.

Any help would be aprecciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this software to control brightness. However, it does not dim backlight, but will soothe your eyes.
Install [Brightness Controller](https://lordamit.github.io/Brightness/) with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install brightness-controller
```

You can control brightness using its slider.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/thumbnail/225x170/appmedia/2014/01/brightness-controller_mac2_1.png))</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I'm able to adjust screen brightness through ubuntu configurations. But I want to recover adjustment through the keyboard and stop with these errors that pop up at the beginning of a session.

Comment: @LuísMuniz You may try these http://askubuntu.com/a/510628/124466, http://askubuntu.com/a/135228/124466, http://askubuntu.com/q/94515/124466.

Comment: @LuísMuniz Another tip: My HP laptop had these problems in Ubuntu 14.04, but they were all solved after installing Ubuntu 16.04